# execute jquery function from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

on my page I update a page dynamically, populated by the database. You choose the state and city, and he tells you the stores available in town. Some cities have a pretty extensive list of stores, so I need a scroll bar. I am using the mCustomScrollbar.

For it to work so I call this script:

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $("#exibe_lojas").mCustomScrollbar({
                scrollButtons:{
                    enable:true
                },
                autoDraggerLength: false
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

But, as I still do not have content, I have to call it after loading my data, and who does this is another javascript file, which makes the query in the database, and displays the result in a div. In view of the result I'm doing this:

```
function stateChanged()
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    { 
        document.getElementById("exibe_cidade").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText
    }
}
```

I think it is here where I put the function of my scroll bar, but as it is in another file; i'm not knowing how to call it. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way would be to place the code into the `stateChanged` method, but if the file content can't be edited, you could listen to content changes on the element with ID "exibe_cidade":

```
$( '#exibe_cidade' ).bind( 'contentchanged', function() {
    $("#exibe_lojas").mCustomScrollbar( {
        // your magic here
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function stateChanged()
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    { 
        document.getElementById("exibe_cidade").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;

        $("#exibe_lojas").mCustomScrollbar({
            scrollButtons:{
                enable:true
            },
            autoDraggerLength: false
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this should work, are you sure the mCustomScrollbar is actually working ?